# Searching for contacts using a list of first/last names

Tags: search, search-results

I've got a list of names that I need to find the contact profiles for. I only have the first and last name, is there a way to search for a batch of people and show up as a list view rather than searching one by one? I've tried search builder and custom seacrch but neither of them seem to have the functionality to search for multiple different names.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange. I don't think there is anything built in. If its a lot of people you have in a spreadsheet, I'd export all the conatcts with contact ids to a spreadsheet and than match these the the people on your list. Delete the rest of the conatacts from the spreadsheet. Then import those contacts as an update (not changing anything), adding them to a new group. Then you can use that group to select the people on your list.

Comment: or you could just try the 'import' set to Match, and track your imports by adding to a Group, as Mick suggests, so you can delete any new ones that get created which you don't want. (Adv Search lets you filter for 'Created' today)